# Please help debug my call scipy library for Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test

Tags: scipy, jupyter-notebook

I am completing an assignment but can not get the right results from a kolmogorov smirnov test for a small sample of observations against a 'norm' distribution.

I have setup a minimal sample in a jupyter notebook with expected kstest results and tried  running this in several environment and reviewed the call for hours. Answer key says my ks_value and p_value are wildly wrong.

But, I cannot  see my error.

- the sample I have is from the test run in the answer key. it is a 1d array, a valid input option.
- sample mean and standard deviation  I compute look right
- if I change ddof it makes a small difference (hint is to use ddof=0)
- norm is a valid distribution for the kstest
- library documentation is at 
  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html#scipy-stats-kstest

Any ideas or comments?
Would you expect a sample =  [0.37, 0.27, 0.69, 0.56, 0.26] compared to a normal distribution to have

- 'KS test statistic' of 0.64  or 0.24

and

- 'p-value' of 0.02 or 0.94

TIA

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import kstest

sample = [0.37, 0.27, 0.69, 0.56, 0.26]
normal_args = (np.mean(sample), np.std(sample, ddof=0))
print('mean', normal_args[0])
print('std', normal_args[1])

ks_value, p_value = kstest(sample, 'norm', normal_args )

print('ks_value', ks_value)
print('p_value', p_value)
print('')
print('#####posted solution')
print('expected ks_value = 0.63919407')
print('expected p_value =  0.01650327')

mean 0.43000000000000005
std 0.1688786546606764
ks_value 0.23881183701141995
p_value 0.9379686201081335

####posted solution
expected ks_value = 0.63919407
expected p_value =  0.01650327
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad. A new guy mistake.

The function calls defines the 3rd argument as "args=()". I had put the 3rd argument in treating the input as a positional. Changing the call to

```
ks_value, p_value = kstest(sample, 'norm', args=(normal_args) )
```

yields the correct response.